# Spell check in the Bash CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, spell-check

Is there any way to do a spell check on the Bash CLI? I tried doing `Ctrl-X Ctrl-E` to edit the command in VIM but for some reason I could not set `set sp` in that VIM session.

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Are you asking about spell checking the commands themselves, or do you want to check text (like in a file)?

Comment: Spell checking the commands, such as `echo "Hello, world!" > file.txt`.

Comment: That's still ambiguous -- I'm still not sure what you're saying.  Do you want to spell check the *commands* (i.e. the `echo` and the `>`) or the English text?

Comment: I would like to spell check the English text. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Common spell checking utilities include [`ispell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ispell/) and [`aspell`](http://aspell.net/).  Other things being equal, I would recommend the latter; but there are legacy reasons to prefer `ispell`, and if it's installed on your system already, and `aspell` is not, it should be fine for English.

Maybe also look at [`hunspell`](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) which, despite its name, is not just for Hungarian.  For the vast majority of the languages of the world which use a (vaguely) alphabetic orthography (and possibly the majority overall), it is vastly better than tools which are based on the limited morphological system of English.

Comment: If you have software that wants `ispell`, there is a compatibility script that makes `aspell` act like `ispell`.  I think it's normally installed when you install `aspell`.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, I installed aspell (*brew install aspell*) and then added the lines below to the end of my ~/.bashrc so that I can use the spell command as I do on other systems:

```
alias spell=spellCheck $1
function spellCheck() {
   for file in "$@"
   do
      let count=`aspell -a < $file | egrep "^\&" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`
      if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
         printf "\n$No spelling errors on $file\n"
      fi
      if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
         printf "\n$count spelling error(s) on $file\n"
         echo ======================================================
         aspell -a < $file  | egrep "^\&" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
      fi
   done
}
```